# How to make an library consumable without adding the repository again

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Kotlin library which uses some external library that I want to expose to the consumer using my library.

I'm using `api`, but as the library is in a specific repository. The consumer is not able to use this without defining this repository there also.

This is what I've defined in my library

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/asbachb/mvn-repo/master/releases"
    }
}
dependencies {
    api "com.github.asbachb:ftp4j:$ftp4j_version"
}
```

Is it possible for me to expose `ftp4j` to the consumer without the consumer needing to add this repository in their dependency?